# ehcache load from DB and read from local disk

Tags: spring, ehcache

How do I force the ehcache to load all the data from DB once, after that i need to read the values from ehcache.

I am seeing examples in which every new search goes to db first and then next hit from cache.

```
getProduct("1") - goes to db - ok
getProduct("1") - goes to cache - ok
getProduct("2") - goes to db - **instead i want this from cache**
getProduct("2") - goes to cache - ok
```

Please advice.

Comment: Checkout [link](http://forums.terracotta.org/forums/posts/list/4335.page). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want up-front loading of a set of information in the cache, this is something you need your application to trigger.

The cache itself does not know the valid values to `getProduct` and so cannot prefetch them on its own.